# how to decrease column values by 20 percent using mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a procutd with this price: **60.33**. When i increase the price to 20% i got like result **72.39** that is correct. but when i am tryng to decrease to 20% i dont have the same price that i had before. i am having **60.37** some one can help me to tell me what i have to do exactly?

This is the script sql i made to that:

```
round(listprice +(listprice *(20/100)),2)//Increase 20%
round(listprice -(listprice *(20/100)),2)//Decrease 20%
```

Comment: This is about arithmetics, not database administration.

Comment: i see...But there is no way to resolve that from sql?

Comment: @mustaccio I agree, but it's easy.

Comment: Sorry, but this is basic math.  And a basic way for hucksters to cheat those who slept through math in school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the reciprocal value of 20%, because you're new value isn't 120% it is the new 100% value.

```
round(listprice * 1.2,2) -- increase by 20%
```

The reciprocal for above +20% would be:

```
round(listprice / 1.2,2) -- decrease by 17.777777%
```

Or put basically: If you want to counteract an increase of 20% then you need to reduce by 17.7777777%.

You can verify this on Windows with the calculator. Beware of the `round()` function!

---

### Mathematics Explanation

Multiplying a value with a number is another way of adding. If you want to add 100% to a given value, then you can multiply the value with 2:

```
listprice * 2
```

If we replace `listprice` with `100` then we have:

```
100 * 2 = 200
```

This is an increase of 100% compared to the starting value of 100.

If you want to increase a value by 20% then you want to add a fifth of the base value. This is the equivalent of multiplying by `1.2`:

```
100 * 1.2 = 120
```

Now multiplying by 1.2 can counteracted by dividing the result by 1.2 again:

```
120 / 1.2 = 100
```

This is the equivalent of what you are looking for. You want to counteract the addition of `listprice +(listprice *(20/100))`.

---

### Working Example

A working example can be found at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f5f0cc0a8e5f97d456ff6f6aff62705) (MySQL 8.0)

---

### Using the Original Addition

After poring over your equation last night and this morning I found a way of using your original "addition".

```
                20   
x = y + ( y * ----- )
               100
```

This can be converted to:

```
                20   
x = y * ( 1 + ----- )
               100
```

Which as you may note is a multiplication again. So if you were to want the original value of `y`, then all you need to do is to divide by original multiplicand:

```
                20   
y = x / ( 1 + ----- )
               100
```

Or written as :

```
          x
     ------------
y =         20        
     (1 + ----- )  
           100
```

In your MySQL equation this would be:

```
listprice = round(listprice / (1 + (20/100)),2)
```

---

### Working Example Using Addition

A working example can be found at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b116e527cb577cd957da8524c6a0a5b6) (MySQL 8.0)

Comment: @Jonh aka hot2use, thanks to reply, but there is something that i did not understand what is the "1.2" because the 20% is 0.2 if i have to make 20/100

Comment: I understant what you mean, your idea is great, unfortunatly that did not work. for exemple i got a normal price at the database with 60.33 i increase as you did and that give me 72.40 it is correct, and i tried to decrease but that gave me 50.28..that is too far from the first result value that i have in my database :(

Comment: That is probably because you did not commit the change to your table, before you conducted the second simple `SELECT`. If you are only doing a `SELECT`then it will not work. I will provide an example.

Comment: ooooh John you are right! i have read your explaination i tried it here that works hahahah thanks. you just saved my day!!